# Run JUnit test with real Service

Tags: spring, service, junit, autowired

I have an external system which I can access specifying URL, username and password into a property file that I match with my application through an XML file

```
<util:properties id="applicationProperties"
        location="classpath:application-resources/my-properties.properties" />
```

This is my service

```
public class RSDSIntegrationServiceImpl implements RSDSIntegrationService {

private static final Log log = Log.getLog( RSDSIntergrationServiceImpl.class );

@Value("${rsds.filestore.workspace}")
private String workspace;

@Autowired
@Qualifier( "oiaNetworkFileStore" )
private IStoreAccess storeAccess;

@Override
public String storeFile(InputStream inputStream, String applicationID) {
    log.info( "Storing file in RSDS for the Online Instalment Arrangement application with ID: " + applicationID );
    return storeAccess.store( workspace , inputStream );
}
```

and I'd like to run a JUnit test to test if the storeFile method will store my file into this external system.

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )    
@ContextConfiguration( locations="htb-config/oia-test-context.xml" )    
public class RSDSIntegrationServiceTest {

@Autowired
    private RSDSIntegrationService rsdsIntegrationService;

@Test

    public void connectivityTest() {
        Assert.assertNotNull( rsdsIntegrationService );
    }
```

Why the assertion fails? What do I miss?

Thanks to all...

Comment: What's in htb-config/oia-test-context.xml ?

Comment: Into the XML, in addition of other info...

Comment: <util:properties id="applicationProperties"
  location="classpath:htb-config/oia-test.properties" />

and into the oia-test.properties... I have the connection parameters for the system I'm trying to test the connection.